# Codesigning a program that runs with MPI

Tags: mpi, code-signing, osx-elcapitan, openmpi

I'm developing some code which I run on OSX with the `mpirun` command. Every time I compile my code, the execution afterwards **opens a bunch of popup dialogs** asking for accepting or refusing *incoming connections*. There are as many popups as MPI ranks I am using. For example, if I run

```
mpirun -np 4 myprogram
```

then I obtain 4 popups.

I know I am supposed to `codesign` something to prevent the firewall to open these popups, so I tried the following commands:

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /opt/local/libexec/openmpi-gcc48/orterun
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /opt/local/bin/mpi*
```

Note that my installation of OpenMPI is in `/opt/local`. Unfortunately, this did not work.

**What should I codesign in order to prevent the firewall to show these popups ?**

Comment: You should sign your executable files.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I cannot do this because they change every time I re-compile. Or is there some way to do it ?

Comment: How about making the code signing part of the compilation steps with your build system?

Comment: @Zulan this code is not supposed to be released on Mac really, and that seems somewhat an awkward practice. Isn't there some standard method to do this outside of the compile process?